# Datepicker no se despliega cuando cargo datos con una busqueda C#, Bootstrap. ASP NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-web-api, datepicker

Tengo un problema estoy realizando una pagina en la cual cuando la cargo hay un boton de busqueda, ingreso un dato y me carga varios textbox. La cuestion es que uno de los textbox lo utilizo para cargar una fecha manualmemte, el mismo queda inhabilitado cuando se hace la carga de los datos 
aqui esta el codigo ASP

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="page-title">
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 30%"></td>
                    <td style="width: 45%; text-align: center">
                        <div>
                            <h4>
                                <p class="description">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbltipo" runat="server" Text="Contrato-Cronograma"></asp:Label>
                                </p>
                                <h4></h4>
                                <h4></h4>
                                <h4></h4>
                                <h4></h4>
                                <h4></h4>
                                <h4></h4>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 25%">
                        <div class="title-env2">
                    <h4>

                    </h4>
                </div>


                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-body">

                <div role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_numRegistroConstruccion">Registro Construccion </label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_numRegistroConstruccion" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="acompleteRegistro" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txt_numRegistroConstruccion" ServiceMethod="GetCliente"
                                        MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServicePath="~/Autocomplete.asmx" CompletionInterval="200">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
                             <asp:Button ID="btn_buscar" runat="server" CssClass="btn2 btn-success" Text="Buscar" OnClick="btn_buscar_Click" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_numContrato">Contrato #</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_numContrato" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_idCliente">Id. Cliente</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_idCliente" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_nombres">Nombres</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_nombres" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_cedula">Cedula</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_cedula" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_numPisos">Num. pisos</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_numPisos" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_areaConstruccion">Area construccion(m2)</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_areaConstruccion" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_fecCaducidad">Fec. Caducidad</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_fecCaducidad" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="ddnivelFedatario">Nivel Construccion:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="ddnivelFedatario" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_idFedatario">Id Fedatario:</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_idFedatario" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_Fedatario">Fedatario asignado:</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_Fedatario" runat="server" class="form-control" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_visitasBase">Visitas Base</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_visitasBase" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_visitasAdicionales">Visitas adicionales</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:Label ID="txt_visitasAdicionales" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_observaciones">Observaciones</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">

                            <asp:Label ID="txt_observaciones" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:Label>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txt_fecha">Fecha </label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_fecha" runat="server" class="form-control datepicker" data-format="dd/mm/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />

                  <asp:GridView ID="gv_lista" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                   <Columns>


                   </Columns>

                                        </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>





            <br />
            <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success btn-icon" ID="btn_guardar" runat="server" Text="GUARDAR" Style="width: 100%; height: 30px" OnClick="btn_guardar_Click" />
            <br />                         

            <br />
            <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success btn-icon" ID="btn_cancelar" runat="server" Text="CANCELAR" Style="width: 100%; height: 30px" OnClick="btn_cancelar_Click" />
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function showAjaxModal(tit, val) {
        jQuery('#modal-7 .modal-body').html(val);
        jQuery('#modal-7 .modal-header .modal-title').html('<p>' + tit + ' </p>');
        jQuery('#modal-7').modal('show', { backdrop: 'static' });
    }

</script>
```

y este el codigo de boton busqueda

protected void btn_buscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dat = new DataTable();
        int registroConstruccion = int.Parse(txt_numRegistroConstruccion.Text.ToString());

```
    dat = contra.ll_cargaContrato(registroConstruccion, idempresa);



    if (dat.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            txt_idCliente.Text = dat.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            txt_nombres.Text = dat.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            txt_cedula.Text = dat.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            //txt_direccion.Text = dat.Rows[0][3].ToString();
            //txt_correo.Text = dat.Rows[0][4].ToString();
            //txt_telefono.Text = dat.Rows[0][5].ToString();
            txt_numContrato.Text =  dat.Rows[0][6].ToString();
            // txt_registroConstruccion.Text = dat.Rows[0][7].ToString();
            txt_numPisos.Text = dat.Rows[0][8].ToString();
            txt_areaConstruccion.Text = dat.Rows[0][9].ToString();
            txt_fecCaducidad.Text = dat.Rows[0][10].ToString();
            //txt_tecnico.Text = dat.Rows[0][11].ToString();
            //txt_emailTecnico.Text = dat.Rows[0][12].ToString();
            //txt_fonoTecnico.Text = dat.Rows[0][13].ToString();
            txt_visitasAdicionales.Text = dat.Rows[0][14].ToString();
            txt_idFedatario.Text= dat.Rows[0][15].ToString();
            ddnivelFedatario.Text = dat.Rows[0][16].ToString();
            txt_visitasBase.Text = dat.Rows[0][17].ToString();
            txt_observaciones.Text = dat.Rows[0][18].ToString();
            txt_Fedatario.Text = dat.Rows[0][19].ToString();

            int numFilas = int.Parse(dat.Rows[0][17].ToString()) + int.Parse(dat.Rows[0][14].ToString());


             DataTable dat1 = new DataTable();



             dat1.Columns.Add("ID");
            dat1.Columns.Add("Fase", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dat1.Columns.Add("Fecha", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dat1.Columns.Add("Observaciones", Type.GetType("System.String"));

            Session["DT"] = dat1;


            int contador = 0;
                      for (int i = 1; i <= numFilas; i++)
                      {


                          foreach (DataColumn colum in dat1.Columns)
                          {
                              DataRow dr = dat1.NewRow();
                              dr["Id"] = i;
                              //dr["Fecha"] = "Responsable " + contador.ToString();
                              //dr["Comentarios"] = "Analista " + contador.ToString();

                              dat1.Rows.Add(dr);
                              contador++;
                          }

                      }
                gv_lista.DataSource = dat1;

               gv_lista.DataBind(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Response.Redirect("apl6.aspx"); }

    }


    //gv_lista.DataBind();
}
```

agradeceria mucho ayudandome con este error que se presenta, por que si non hago la caarga de los datos de busqueda, ahi si se presenta el datepicker sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que el problema es que, luego del post, el UpdatePanel elimina todos los elementos del HTML y los vuelve a crear, entonces, el datepicker se elimina.  Seguramente estás creando el datepicker a través de JavaScript con una librería de DatePicker para Bootstrap, no?  Si es así, después de las actualizaciones del UpdatePanel deberías volver a crear el datepicker, por ejemplo, agregando este script al final de la página:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var requestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    requestManager.add_endRequest(function () { $('.datepicker').datepicker(); });
</script>
```

Si creas el datepicker de otra forma sólo deberías cambiar el "$('.datepicker').datepicker();" por lo que utilices para crearlo.

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!